# Why does my form submit and ignore validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I am trying to figure out why [jquery validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/) does not stop my form from being submitted? When the submit button is pressed the form posts correctly but seems to ignore the validation error (This field is required) even if the input field is left blank.

The form

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#message").hide();

  //Define your validation rules.
  $(function() {
    $("#myform").validate({

    });
    $("#submitButtonId").on("click", function(e) {
      var formdata = $("#myform").serialize();
      //Post form data
      $.post('php_includes/simple_insert.php', formdata, function(data) {
        //Process post response
        $("#message").html(data);
        $("#message").fadeIn(500);
        $("#message").fadeOut(500);
      });

      //Reset Form
      $('#myform')[0].reset();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form class="form-inline" action="" id="myform" method="post">

  <!-- Text input-->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="bill_cost"></label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input id="bill_cost" name="bill_cost" type="text" placeholder="Bill Cost" class="form-control input-lg" required>

    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Button -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="submit1"></label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <button type="submit" id="submitButtonId" name="submit1" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: The "click on the submit button" event happens *before* the "submit the form" event, and it's the "submit the form" event that has the validation code. Because you are sending the `post` request in the "click on the submit button" event, it isn't getting to the validation before then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, use submitHandler to do other things for a valid form:

```
    $("#myform").validate({
        submitHandler : function() {
            var formdata = $("#myform").serialize();
           //Post form data
           $.post('php_includes/simple_insert.php', formdata, function(data){
             //Process post response
             $("#message").html(data);
             $("#message").fadeIn(500); 
             $("#message").fadeOut(500); 
           });

          //Reset Form
           $('#myform')[0].reset(); 

           }
        });
```

Comment: damn, you just beat me to it

Comment: This doesn't explain why OP's code doesn't work though ;)

Comment: because even though validations are there, he has not checked if form is valid or not for sending ajax - as user click button ajax will just execute, so using submitHandler we can check that if valid then only send ajax request

Comment: Worked great. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Remove a **Required** tag in bill cost text box.then you check the  validation is ignored